# Javascript DOMContentLoaded has a mysterious 5-10 second delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap, domcontentloaded

I'm really confused about this. I have a reasonably dynamic page on a test site which uses Bootstrap's carousel (but I'm hoping it's my code, not theirs, that's wrong).

Test page can be found here: http://bit.ly/ZjLl19

What you'll notice is as follows...

- The page starts to load
- The staff portraits begin to appear
- Then... **nothing happens for about 5-10 seconds**
- After 5-10 seconds, a carousel appears with staff biographies and larger portraits

Why is there this delay? I've looked in Webkit debugger and I can just see idle time in the timeline whilst `DOMContentLoaded` runs, before anything else happens. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Uncached, the page is quite content-heavy, it takes about 6 secs before all images are loaded (as watched from the Network tab of Chrome's inspector).

Comment: It's still in development, and before going live I'm going to optimise the images, minify the CSS, etc.

Comment: Of course, but isn't that what's causing your problems?

Comment: I see what you mean, but no - I don't think it is. I can see for me in the timeline view around 7 seconds of empty space - after all assets have been loaded and requests have been made.

Comment: Hmm the plot thickens, check out the timeout on this timer: http://imgur.com/opEXNQU Not sure what it's doing, but might provide you with some more info to track this issue down.

Comment: (although it might just be the timer for the carousel #duh)

Comment: **I have placed my observations in the answer below, and I am very sure that is the bug you are looking for. It has nothing to do with optimization of the page and images, and most likely caused by the plugin. Recommended course of actions are also included.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually an easy fix. Simply apply the active class to the first element to show it (Or which ever one you want to display first). Otherwise you're waiting until dom has loaded and the carousel has been initialised to do that for you.

So this below would do the trick and display the carousel immediately without having to wait for JS:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item mtt-item active">...</div>
    <div class="item mtt-item">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obviously you can optimize the page but the carousel does not display as you don't have an active slide set or the outter container hides the slides. You are literally waiting until the carousel has loaded via dom ready to show something. You want to show the carousel is there before the carousel has loaded. You images have already loaded and is not the issue. The 10s delay is due to the fact that your script waits until your page is ready.

I tested this with an emulated connection. The site loads fine. I would obviously recommend to still optimize the page where possible as mentioned above.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you because this answer fixed it perfectly and it works as expected now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why someone down voted this. I had tested it and it worked perfectly. Thanks for accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

***Points to note:***

1) You paused your carousel on init. This may explain the initial pause. The carousel auto continues to the next slide, showing the subsequent slides after the default delay, [which apparently is 5000ms](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel).

```
$('.carousel.paused-by-default').carousel('pause');
```

2) The paused carousel, after the initial pause, displays itself using this code:

```
info = setTimeout(function(){reveal_content();}, 500);
```

3) **[UPDATE - IGNORE FIRST TWO OBSERVATIONS]**

THE CAROUSEL SEEMS TO BE STARTING FROM SLIDE **-1**. As there is no slide **-1**, the height of the carousel stays at `0px`. The height of the carousel ONLY updates to `560px` AFTER the first slide has completed it's animation. This is why there is no animation for the first slide, and it just seems to *pop* out of nowhere, after the default slide delay of 5000, PLUS additional animation speed of about one second (as mentioned in point #1). To fix this, use both solutions below.

====================================

***Ways that might help you fix the problem:***

1) Add this just before the closing bracket of `$(document).ready()` function, to display the first slide immediately:

```
$('.carousel').carousel(0);
```

2) If previous point did not completely solve the problem, set height of `#mtt-carousel` and `.carousel-inner` to 560px, add this before the previous JS statement in #1.

```
$('#mtt-carousel, .carousel-inner').css('height', '560px');
```

or CSS:

```
#mtt-carousel, .carousel-inner { height: 560px !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, +1. The premise of your answer was correct but the fix was easier than you stated. I simply needed to add `active` as a class to the first element which seemed to fix the -1 error. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to do the following :

1. Reduce the size of your images .
2. Combine your css files into one .
3. Combine js files .
4. Gzip css and js files . Compression will drastically improve load time .
5. Minify css and js , removing unwanted space in these files will reduce the size of them.
6. You can take advantage of browser caching by specifying expiry date and age of resources.

Comment: Some of them, yes, but the problem was not to do with page optimisation, it was actually to do with the Javascript logic as I suspected.